# JPA and List<> variable in my Class

Tags: java, jpa

I have a low Exprience in Java and also in JPA.
I have this Code here as a class and i've got a problem with siblings variable,
everything works automatic except siblings,
i have no idea how could i even do it manually. The Code is like this,

```
public class Child extends AbstractEntity{

@ManyToMany
private List<Child> siblings;

String name;
String lastname;
Date bod;
```

and in my Form Class i treid this one,

```
List<Child> siblings=new ArrayList<Child>();

TextField name=new TextField("Name");
TextField lastname=new TextField("LastName");
DateField bod=new DateField("BOD");
.
.   
.
```

then i filled siblings with another form with name , lastname , bod fields,

```
Child child=new Child(txtName.getValue(),txtLast.getValue(),date.getValue());
siblings.add(child);
```

after updating, all those fields will update except siblings.

its like somehow siblings in my FormClass is not connected to the siblings in the ChildClass.

The Codes for Updating and other Parts of application is working and the only problem that i got, is just this    List<> variable.

could anyone please guide me somehow or helping me...
Thanks!

Comment: The Child class has a relation with the Child class itself. This Form class is NEVER going to be "connected" to the Child relation siblings since they are utterly unrelated. Post the FULL Form and Child classes

Comment: @neil-stockton what if i make a new class name Siblings extends AbstractEntity and the try my siblings var as List<Siblings> siblings; is it gonna be the same?  thanks by the way for guiding ;)

Comment: doesn't work.. .

Comment: go back to your question as I already asked and POST the full Form and Child classes. You can easily see what a M-N relation is supposed to look like in JPA tutorials